# How to disable/block access to Portable Hotspot feature

Tags: parental-control, google-family-link

My client asked me to configure Google Family Link (parental control) for his daughters phone/tablet/s, I did and everything worked great, but the little one is clever as a fox and found at age 9 a sorta bypass... She enables the portable hotspot to give internet to the laptop and even if the phone remains a brick till morning, the laptop is fully operational.

A few caveats, the phone/s are not rooted, and I might need to do the same with a tablet/s, also not rooted.

So far what I've found and tried is an AppLock app to lock the Settings option, but wondered if there was another more elegant solution, that didn't block all settings.

Cheers.

Comment: It would be best to take away the and tablet laptop at bedtime.  Some kids are crafty, and can bypass any parental-control software.  ❧  Failing that, you could lock down the laptop, and set up time and/or network restrictions.  What operating system is installed on the laptop?